# Django on docker; Staticfiles disappearing

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn, django-staticfiles

I am trying to deploy my django project using docker nginx and gunicorn.
My Issue is that the staticfiles I use for my project are missing from the container.

when in the project:

```
ls staticfiles/
css  disconnected.html  images  lib  nothing.css
```

after going into the container with `docker exec -it foo_web_1 /bin/sh`

```
ls staticfiles/
admin
```

my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./foo-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn foo-app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/foo-app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/foo-app/web/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/foo-app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/foo-app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 2375:80
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

the nginx.conf file:

```
upstream foo-app {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://foo-app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/foo-app/web/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /home/foo-app/web/mediafiles/;
    }

}
```

the part of the settings.py that relates to staticfiles:

```py
STATIC_URL = "/staticfiles/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
]
```

Inside my dockerfile I define the following:

```
ENV HOME=/home/foo-app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/foo-app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
```

and later I simply copy the entire project in using

```
COPY . $APP_HOME
```

All other file show up perfectly fine, and I have tried remove and rebuild the entire project to avoid artifacts to no avail.

Comment: Are those files in your `.dockerignore`, maybe?

Comment: The best practice with Django and Docker I've found is to run `collectstatic` within the Docker build process, and serve the static files with e.g. http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Comment: The project currently does not include a `.dockerignore` file.

Comment: Have you tried to run: `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: the whole setup works fine outside the container (and even inside the container, as long as I manually add the staticfiles), they just get deleted during build despite never being explicitly touched.

Comment: `python manage.py collectstatic` is run in my entrypoint script, but I also tested to remove the command without any difference in result

Comment: Have you defined `STATIC_ROOT`?

Comment: At the time of making the post I had not defined it but currently it is set to 
`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")`, the issue persists.

Comment: Please ensure that docker is not using previously cached layers.

Comment: I always use `docker system prune` between runs. I now separated staticfiles and static with the latter containing my staticfiles and the former being the `STATIC_ROOT`. The issue still persist, but I can now run `python manage.py collectstatic` from within the container to copy them over. seeing that main entrypoint script is:  
```sh
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic

echo "startupscript successful"
exec "$@"
```
I would guess that the issue lies with `command: gunicorn foo-app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem got resolved by separating `STATIC_ROOT` from the location of my staticfiles and then adding `python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear` to my startupscript.